# Populate a 2d array from a string and put the ASCII value of the individual characters into it

Tags: java

I am creating a program that will read a txt file(from another master txt file), take the string which is a bunch of letters(@-K), and then populate a 2d array with the ASCII value of the characters in the string. So I have successfully created the 2d array and read the file. The problem is that my array is only being populated by the first letter of the string file, and not going through the entire file. I have an if statement that I believe should read through the file and populate it properly, however it is not doing it. Can't figure out what im doing wrong. Here is the code.

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
  {
    String txtfile;
    String txtfilecontents;
    int matrix[][]= new int [24][34];
    int row=0;
    int col=0;
    BufferedReader masterfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("imageFileList.txt")); 
    while((txtfile=masterfile.readLine())!=null)                                              //reads master text file
    {
      BufferedReader imagefile= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtfile));
      while((txtfilecontents=imagefile.readLine())!=null)                                     //reads text file within master file
      {
        for(int i=0;i<txtfilecontents.length();i++)                                           
        {
          if(col ==34)
          {
            col = 0;
            row++;
          }
          if(row ==24)
          {
            col=0;
            row=0;
            break;
          }
          matrix[row][col] = (int)txtfilecontents.charAt(i)-64;                                  //instead of adding every character it only adds the first one until it fills up the 2d array
          col++;
        }
        System.out.println(txtfilecontents);
        for(row=0;row<24;row++)
        {
          for(col=0;col<34;col++)
            System.out.printf("%4d",matrix[row][col]);
          System.out.println();
        }
      }

      System.out.println(txtfile);
    }


  }
```

Here is an example of what a txtfile has in it.

```
AKHIICG@KDHDJKGHHHFGECEGHEIEHDCBF@DB@DDIABHI@GHAFAFHEGCECEJ@GHKJCBGFFFH@IB@JB@KKBFAGABCJHJ@AEDIABGI@DDCJHCAK@@FBKHGB@KFI@KKEJCJFHBDAJBAJKCGEE@DFDBBD@GDEIJAIKBHCDH@AAJK@EJHEGGKGJEJ@@F@@AGDFECCFIFHDEGHBJCABEKBFIIEBJGFHKJJFKFKDEKHBBEIBAHBGKDHKFKCAEJFDHEHK@@AIIBF@EEBB@BEGEBIKDJGKEJKHKHAJJDGFKFGIKI@ECH@FBEEGKDACKGHAIBCJGDJCEKD@K@AGGHGACHCE@HCEDI@FDJDGIJAJFCEFHEBDBGIIGJAFEGGFHJBIHBICB@EDDFEDFBKACJ@JCKKAKEJACICEBIJEFIICH@J@CCE@EJI@BKEFAGAJKKEDHICC@@@DJEGIHFDHDCJGJECHGCBIHC@K@FEHECEKKJAABFAAFA@EHFBFAEHBFCEFDBDKCB@BFGBBKG@@GKBKJEHI@H@DH@IJ@FFICEDBDJECA@@DKHAIFJII@DDEBI@IGIFJ@@BFC@IHGCJEAG@CAF@CCFEC@AFKDDKKAD@K@HDBDAIDIKCGJJGEECGIIECDGDHHBC@FJDGJJDB@AKBBGEEIFK@D@BCCG@IAEJEECDCFBBE@AK@EAEDGCEKIBDKHICG@DFDDGJGHGDE@CGIEAEEHBKFCBICDGADBHDEABJGHCEIDDJD@BEEJA@JFB@IFGDA@GAGDAEDBDCFGKEJEDDKFCE@FHJIB@JDAEECHBJCDAEFAHBDJC@FH
```

Also I have added a bunch of print statements in the file so I could see what my output was coming up with, but it will be taken out later.

Comment: Given the example input, what should the expected output be?  Also, subtracting 64 will not give you the ASCII value of anything...

Comment: the example output should be the 2d array populated with the ascii values of the input. The subtracting 64 is just to get me 0-11 values(@ ASCII value is 64, minus 64=0, etc.)

Comment: So should your output be the the ASCII values or the ASCII values minus 64...?

Comment: Final product it will be ASCII values minus 64. Right now im just trying to get the output to actually come out right.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=0;i<txtfilecontents.length();i++)                                           
        {
          for(row=0;row<24;row++)
            for(col=0;col<34;col++)
              matrix[row][col] = (int)txtfilecontents.charAt(i);                              //instead of adding every character it only adds the first one until it fills up the 2d array
        }
```

You are filling the matrix with the charAt(i), so at the end, the matrix will be filled with the last character in the string

Try something like this:

```
row = 0; 
col = 0;
for(int i=0;i<txtfilecontents.length();i++)                                           
{
    //Insert the char into the matrix
    matrix[row][col] = (int)txtfilecontents.charAt(i);

    //Move the matrix position for the next character
    row++;
    if (row >= 24){
        row = 0;
        col++;
        if (col >= 34){
            System.out.println("Matrix out of space");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My print statement shows that is exactly what it is doing. I tried the appraoch @Floris suggested, but it only populated the first number, then gave me a bunch of 0's.

Comment: @Student added a possible solution to my answer

Comment: Thank you I used something very similar to fix it however, now I am getting an error and it will not read the next txt file. I updated my code in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

The loop

```
for(int i=0;i<txtfilecontents.length();i++)                                           
        {
          for(row=0;row<24;row++)
            for(col=0;col<34;col++)
              matrix[row][col] = (int)txtfilecontents.charAt(i);                              //instead of adding every character it only adds the first one until it fills up the 2d array
        }
```

Saves the character at every location. You need to compute the address where you want to save, rather than go around the inner for loops. Or perhaps update the counter `i` in the innermost loop, and set a flag to break out if you reach the end of the string.

Example of first approach (**edited - was not incrementing col**)

```
row=0;col=0;
for(int i=0;i<txtfilecontents.length();i++)                                           
    {
         if (col == 34) {
            col=0; row++;
         }
    if (row==24) break;
    matrix[row][col] = (int)txtfilecontents.charAt(i);        
    col++; // <<<<< added this line!!                      
    }
```

Comment: I had omitted one line in my code... Wasn't incrementing `col`. It should now work.